# How to write a jenkins file defining 5 reposiotries together

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How to write a jenkins file defining 5 repositories together ,different repo needs to do different build jobs

Comment: Every repo should have it's own independent Jenkinsfile(part of the source control) that defines build steps. What are you trying to accomplish by putting them together?

Answer (score 0):

You use one stage per Repo build. You can checkout different Repos using 'checkout'.

Example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Repo 1') {
            steps {
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
                              branches: [[name: '*/master']],
                              doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
                              extensions: [], 
                              submoduleCfg: [], 
                              userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'YourRepo1']]])
                    echo "Build Repo1" 
            }
        }
        stage('Repo 2') {
            steps {
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
                              branches: [[name: '*/master']],
                              doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
                              extensions: [], 
                              submoduleCfg: [], 
                              userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'YourRepo2']]])
                    echo "Build Repo2" 
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

For a cleaner solution you need to add some paths being check outed in an build in.